# What am I supposed to do about the error “Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)” in my code calling re-search-forward?

Tags: search, replace, error

I have several interactive functions that pretty straightforwardly do `re-search-forward` and `replace-match` in a loop. Once in a while, if I have a region selected and do the replacement in it, `re-search-forward` throws an error with the message `Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)`, and the last `replace-match` only replaces a part of the match, leaving some of its tail untouched. This error message is mightily uninformative, and I have no idea what it's trying to tell me and what I am supposed to do. I tried watching the values of the point and the search boundaries, and at least I can tell that the point doesn't seem to get outside of the boundaries. I also use `save-match-data` if I'm doing fancy string manipulation in the function.

This seems to never happen if I don't use the region, and instead invoke the command on the current line. The only difference in this case is that I don't get the values for the search boundaries from `(interactive "r")`, but take `(line-beginning-position)` and `(line-end-position)`, then hand those to `goto-char` and `re-search-forward` in the same way as with a region.

The code is like this:

```el
(defun oh-woe (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (unless (region-active-p)
    (setq beg (line-beginning-position))
    (setq end (line-end-position)))
  (goto-char beg)
  (while (re-search-forward "foo" end t)
    (replace-match "barbaz" t t)))
```

I might hypothesize that matches at the end of the search boundary pose a difficulty for `re-search-forward`, particularly if `replace-match` already did something before that position. However, lots of the time replacement in a region works fine, and only in some cases it errors out (100% reproducibly, though). Plus, presumably the last call to `re-search-forward` would just return nil if the match doesn't fit, since that's what the boundary argument is for.

One would also think that `re-search-forward` should use a marker for the boundary parameter, when it's called in a loop—to account for the text shifting after `replace-match`. But, judging by the help and the manual, it doesn't support markers—and several examples of the use of this function that I've seen, just specify a static position. Should I use a marker manually, retrieving the position each time in the loop?

Update: some further investigation: `Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)` is in fact thrown by `re-search-forward` when the search boundary is before the current point. Guess I didn't watch the values that well.

Comment: Some further investigation: `Invalid search bound (wrong side of point)` is in fact thrown by `re-search-forward` when the search boundary is before the current point. I guess I didn't watch the values that well.

Comment: Add the info from your comment to your question, if you think it might help others. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Could you please say a couple words on what is meant by “Comments can be deleted at any time”? This is not even my first account on SE, but the first time I hear about this.

Comment: Dunno more than that. Moderators can delete any comment, and the person who wrote a comment can delete that comment. The point is that Q&A need to stand on their own. Comments are not searchable, for instance - either on SE or by Google etc. search. SE is Q&A for everyone, and the typical access/discovery is by internet search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use a marker manually

Yes, if you are repeatedly searching and replacing within the same initial `beg end` region, you need to use a marker to ensure that the bounds remain sane from one iteration to the next.

> retrieving the position each time in the loop?

It's likely sufficient to simply set a marker for the original `end` position -- it will be adjusted at each replacement.

(Remember to `set-marker` to nil when you're done with it.)

> judging by the help and the manual, it doesn't support markers

It does.  That might be considered a documentation bug so you might `M-x report-emacs-bug` for that if it hasn't been raised already.

(For the code in question, see the `fix_position` function in `buffer.c` which is used by `search_command` in `search.c`.  I'm looking at the code for 28.2.)

Comment: Seems to work, at least for now. Apparently I was wrong about the point staying in the bounds. Regarding “remember to set-marker to nil”—the manual says that markers get garbage-collected, though I guess I could relieve Emacs of some labor before the GC cycle comes.

Comment: There have also been some Emacs bugs that resulted in this error. When reported they've been fixed. If you (OP) don't find a solution then you might want to report the problem, with a reproducible recipe starting from `emacs -Q`: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.